# RSpec .and and block expectations

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to combine two custom matchers using block expectations.

This is the example:

```
expect{puts "test"}.to matcher1.and matcher2
```

And these are the matchers:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :matcher1 do |resource|
  supports_block_expectations

  match do |actual|
    puts "before matcher1"
    actual[]
    puts "after matcher1"
    true
  end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :matcher2 do
  supports_block_expectations

  match do |actual|
    puts "before matcher2"
    actual[]
    puts "after matcher2"
    true
  end
end
```

And the output I'm getting is:

```
before matcher2
before matcher1
test
after matcher1
after matcher2
```

While I'm expecting:

```
before matcher2
test
after matcher2
before matcher1
test
after matcher1
```

Why is my proc only called once, and why the strange nesting?
Is there a way to achieve what I want without repeating the block?

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in [this reported issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/748), `and` was not meant to be that way, and matchers should not be used to alter behaviour on the subject (as I was trying to do).